# React implementing console-feed as top of the hoc

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components and want to HOC them all together, When:

```
const ComponentB = ({configs}) => {
  return function(wrappedComp) {
    ...do some stuff
    return <wrappedComp />
  }
}

const App= () => return <app />
const configs = { someconfigs }

const appWithCompB = ComponentB(configs)(App)
```

This works fine, then I tried to implement the console-feed lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-feed

And it has to be at the top of the HOC chain to monitor stuff, So I add:

```
const ConsoleLogs = (CompB) => {
  ...some console log stuff
  return <CompB />
}
```

Then, connect them all:

```
const logsAppWithCompB = ConsoleLogs(ComponentB(configs)(App))
```

It throws errors:

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Forgive me but the original codes are too long, and I already test that each components works as expected individually, ConsoleLogs too if put in the App component, but since it only load AFTER ComponentB, it will miss some logs from ComponentB, thus it has to moved to the top of HOC. I just had no idea how to do the HOC thing here..

Any help will be appreciated, thanks